# Should I make a race condition check on a parallel sed executions on the same file?if yes then how to lock the file then

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have many scripts shell that are executing at the same time and they make sed on the same file. So there is a risk that the sed command execute at the same time and on the same file. If yes,why.

Should I make a race condition check on a parallel sed executions on the same file?

If yes, how to lock that file.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is modified by one or more instances of your script then you might want to lock it. In this case you should avoid the execution of multiple changes in parallel or even reads during a file change. There are different lock techniques you can use. For example you can use flock to get an exclusive lock immediately before starting a file change and release the same lock immediately after the change has been "committed".

If your file is not modified during the script execution I don't see any reason to lock it. Multiple reads of the same file in parallel are ok.